# for-loop to check which div was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I got a function like that

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#id1");
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the     container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.fadeOut();
    }

    var container2 = $("#id2");
    if (!container2.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container2.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container2.fadeOut();
    }
}
```

It basically checks, if the click happens outside the div and if so, the div fades out. However, I have like 15-20 to check and wonder, whether there is a shorter solution than copy&paste for this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: what's wrong with `$(this).fadeOut();`? You can use a selector to restrict it to the divs you want.

Comment: still I have to go through all ids. I was looking for something like var ids=['#id1','#id2','#id3'...] and a function that checks if one of these is the clicked div, if not fade exactly this one out

Comment: Have you considered giving each div the same class and iterating through using `.each`?

Comment: Still possible in one line when you give all divs a class: `$('.clickableDiv').on('click', function() { $('.clickableDiv').not($(this)).fadeOut(); });`

Answer (score 1):

Give every div the same class and try this:

```
 $(".yourClass").each(function() {

    if (!this.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && this.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        this.fadeOut();
    }

});
```